# Setting a non-transparent background color to chart.js before uploading

Tags: chart.js

I have a canvas which is declared like this:

```
<canvas class="grph" id="log_graph"></canvas>
```

After drawing a line chart on it, I want to upload it to a server, so I do this:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('log_graph'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    
var upload = (blob) => {
    var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append('img', blob, 'filename.png');

    $.post({
        url: `${app.server}/upload-img`,
        data: formdata,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: (data) => {
            console.log(`rc for upload: ${data}`);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.warn("Error, status = " + textStatus + ", " +
                "error thrown: " + errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
canvas.toBlob(upload, 'image/png');
```

Unfortunately, **the uploaded chart is transparent**, and doesn't look good on dark-style image viewers. **I want to set the background to solid white**, but it seems that *chart.js* does not support that.

It is easy to set the **background color on screen** using the background-color css style, but this does not affect the uploaded image which still gets a transparent color.

Answer (score 2):

The way I've done it is as follows: I save the state of the canvas, fill in the background, export, then restore to get rid of the background.

Transposed into code, this gives the following code:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('log_graph'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.save();
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-over';
ctx.fillStyle = "white";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
/*
 EXPORT CODE
*/
ctx.restore();
```

Comment: Thank you, good to know! 
Just wondering, why fillRect() is not covering the chart?

Comment: By default, the globalCompositeOperation property is set to "source-over", which, to quote the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation), _draws new shapes on top of the existing canvas content_.
If you set it to "destination-over", it will draw behind the existing content. In this case, as the chart is transparent, it colours the background

Answer (score 0):

So one solution which I found was to create an empty canvas, fill it with solid white, and then copy the chart on top of it, and then upload that new canvas. It goes like this:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('log_graph'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

// we want to set white background to the canvas, so we create a temporary canvas for that:
// create new canvas, same size as original:
var canvas2 = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas2.width = canvas.width;
canvas2.height = canvas.height;
var ctx2 = canvas2.getContext('2d');
ctx2.fillStyle = 'white';
ctx2.fillRect(0, 0, canvas2.width, canvas2.height);
ctx2.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0);

var upload = ... (same as above)

// very important: use canvas2 here!
canvas2.toBlob(upload, 'image/png');
```

I hope this knowledge sharing will help others!